# How to join three collections with a one to many relationship in mongodb...maybe mapreduce or any other way?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, join

I have three collections that look like

**User** : user_hostname,user_mac_address,user_first_seen

**Router** : router_mac, router_ip, router_name

**session** : user_mac, router_mac, user_ip, user_duration( many different users and routers in different combinations)

So I want to create a new collection with all the information of these tables... i would like for it to be joined in such a way where for each session I can have the router info and user info attached to the session....there are currently over 3 million sessions in the session collection.

**Map Function**

```
router_map = function(){
var values = {
              router_ip :this.router_ip
              router_name: this.router_name};
emit(this.router_mac, values);};

session_map = function(){
var values = {
              user_duration = this.user_duration
              user_mac = this.user_mac
              user_ip= this.user_ip};
emit(this.router_mac,values);};
```

**Reduce Function**

```
r=function(key,values){
 var result = {};
 values.forEach(function(value){
 var field ;
     for(field in value){
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(field)){
        result[field] = value [field];
}}});
return result;};


res=db.router.mapReduce(router_map,r,{out :{reduce :'routersession'}})
res=db.session.mapReduce(session_map,r,{out :{reduce :'routersession'}})
```

**Result**

```
db.routersession.find();


routersession : "_id"=*router mac* , values { "routerip" =data, "routername" = data, "user_duration"= data,"user_ip" = data,"usermac"=data}
```

I only get the first session linked with the router where i want all of the session under the router associated with it....when i put the other way it doesnt work... and i still want to  join a third table to it.

I would also like to do queries like total number of unique session for each router.

I am new to mongodb and I am lost any help would be appreciated. Also let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: It is a really boring question but I will ask it anyway - [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: There's no such thing as a JOIN in MongoDB on the database server, nor a work-around. You'd need to do it in application code.

Comment: So if I use php to pull the info from each different collection in the database and then store it into a one new collection that I create.. would this be efficient????...will this even work???